# Chrome crashes but stays displayed on external screen and I can't remove it

Tags: display, google-chrome, crash

I've got MacBook Pro with macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and an external monitor connected through "j5create JDC 381" USB-C to HDMI adapter.

Weird thing sometimes happens when using Chrome - when it's on the external screen it sometimes stops responding. I have to kill it through *Activity Monitor* BUT the **window stays displayed** even after the process is killed. It completely makes the monitor unusable and I can't do anything about it - I tried unplugging the HDMI adapter, power off/on the monitor, switch display mode to mirror and back, etc. Only reboot helps.

Any ideas how to "unblock" the external screen without reboot when something like this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Mojave 10.14.6.

The j5Create worked perfectly until installing the supplemental update to the OS.  With Apple trying to fix blacked-out/locked screen issue, whatever they did in the update broke j5Create.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was the USB-C to HDMI adaptor.  I changed brands, I now have insignia (best buy brand) and the issue went away.  I don't know if it was a compatibility issue or if I just got a bad one... I don't know what about the different adaptor fixed it.

Comment: Adapters are usually the weakest link. I've found from personal and professional experience that Belkin® and Anker® brand adaptors are top of the line. (Disclaimer: no financial ties to Belkin or Anker.)